# Does any lifeforms can make a haploid cell from any other cell without meiosis?

Tags: genetics

Like the title says, is it possible to produce haploid cells without meiosis?

Comment: I don't think so, but it is possible to transfer the nucleus of a haploid cell to the body of a diploid cell and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

**The question is a bit unclear**

> Can you produce haploid cells without meiosis?

The question is a bit unclear. for two reasons

1. What do you mean by "you". You mean can we do such thing with modern technology or do you mean does it ever happen or do you does it ever happen in human cells.
2. It is also unclear what from. Are you implicitly asking whether "you" (whatever 'you' mean in your sentence) can make a haploid cell from a diploid cell or form anything?

**Answer**

In this answer, I will assume that the question is

> Does any lifeforms can make a haploid cell from any other cell without meiosis?

The answer is yes. Many organisms have a long haploid stage during which many mitosis occur. Haploid cells undergoing mitosis results into two haploid cells.

You might want to read more about [life-cycle (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_life_cycle), especially the sections on haplontic life-cycles and haplo-diplontic life cycles.

Comment: I think these are great answers that will cover OP's curiosity, but the question isn't really up to our standards - can you edit the original question to fit your answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. English isn't my mother-tongue, but you assumed the question correct Remi. I had a lecture about Saccharomyces cerevisiae, and wasn't sure if the budding generates haploid cells. But if I understood it correct, an "a" mating type spore can generate a haploid "alpha" cell without meisosis, right?